# Can anyone identify these ships? And what year?

Tags: naval

[image][image]I found pictures from a house my friend is going to buy and remodel and I find these pictures very interesting. In the back they have a red stamp with the word Kodak 69 pa

Comment: The top left picture looks like a vietnam era riverine armored troop carrier ["tango boat"](http://www.militaryfactory.com/ships/detail.asp?ship_id=Armored-Troop-Carrier-ATC). Can't help with the other images.

Comment: All of them seem to be from Vietnam war era i.e. the 1960s

Comment: The bottom  boat remind of a converted type Harbour Defence Motor Launch -boat. Produced by the British Navy during WW2 and later returned to the US (under lend-en-lease). They remained in service till the late '60. The picture is very unclear though

Comment: Thank yall for the quick responses. This gives me a good lead way to get more information. I greatly appreciate your time.

Comment: The *colour process* reminds me of world war two colour prints I have seen, which still had a quite primitive "fixing". I am not sure there is a way to tell for sure the vintage unless someone can count the stars on the flag in the first picture: 48 => before 1959, 50 => on or after.

Answer (score 11):

It's probably not going to be very easy to identify the top two pictures, but the bottom picture appears to be the light cargo ship [USS Mark (AKL 12)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Mark_(AG-143)). Note that Wikipedia uses its WWII registration number - see the hull's entry on the [Naval Vessel Register](http://www.nvr.navy.mil/NVRSHIPS/DETAILS/AKL12.HTM).

[image: USS Mark]

<sup>Image from http://www.mrfa.org/akl12.html</sup>

The photo paper stamp would put the ship in theater during Vietnam, where it both ran supplies and assisted in supporting the "[Brown Water navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown-water_navy)" operating in the Mekong Delta. That would date the photo sometime between 1966 and 1969 (probably later based on the stamps on the back of the print).

You can find some additional information about the ship's service history at the [Mobile Riverine Force Association website](http://www.mrfa.org/akl12.html).